# Clipboard cleared on quit

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, clipboard

I want to create an application in electron that adds some data to the clipboard and then exits. I got to the point where it is perfectly adding the data to the clipboard and I can paste it wherever.

The issue is that as soon as the app quits the clipboard is cleared.
So I am wondering if there is a way around this, and if it is related to my code or an OS level issue.

In short this is what I have

```
const { app, clipboard } = require("electron");

app.on("window-all-closed", function() {
  if (process.platform !== "darwin") {
    clipboard.writeText("abcd");
    app.quit();
  }
});
```

Comment: is it possible that the function to write to clipboard never actually gets called ?

Comment: It gets called and it is working. If I remove the `app.quit()` call it works as expected(the text is copied to the clipboard)... With the only downside of the application not closing

Comment: What I mean is: are you sure it gets called without removing app.quit() ? If it's an async function it may not get called because the app.quit gets called first.

Comment: Ah, well I couldn't find any documentation stating that it is async, and it doesn't seem to take a callback function. To be sure I delayed the call to app.quit with a 3 second timeout and the problem remained. I'll admit, not the best experiment, but I don't know how else to test

Comment: It doesn't appear to be async, but if it was it wouldn't be called until the end of the `window-all-closed` callback function was reached, so that test wouldn't help anything. I can't find anything that references clearing the clipboard on exit or anything else that seems to indicate that it does that...

Comment: *"...or an OS level issue"* Which OS?

Comment: @Herohtar yes, but if I delay `app.quit` with `setTimeout` for a couple of seconds wouldn't `all-closed` be completed first and then call `app.quit()`?
or am I missunderstanding javascript?
@AuxTaco I am running arch linux

Comment: @munHunger Actually, you're right, that should let the execution continue out of the callback function so an async function should be able to complete.

Comment: fyi your code works on windows.

Answer (score 1):

I put a break point in `window-all-closed` event and I didn't see it trigger when app was quitting. But when I put `clipboard.writeText("abcd");` into `before-quit` event and it works perfectly:

```
app.on('before-quit', (event) => {
  clipboard.writeText("abcd");
});
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Did you try to put it in to `'quit'` instead? Is there any `preventDefault` trigger?

Comment: @munHunger could you please remove clipboard.writeText in `window-all-closed` then try again?

Answer (score 0):

```
app.on('before-quit', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const clipboardy = require('clipboardy');
  clipboardy.writeSync('');
});
```

import clipboardy nodejs package into your package.json.